# Convert list of subclass to list of superclass

Tags: c++

I'm trying to convert a `std::set<B>` to `std::set<A>`, where:

```
class A {

}

class B : public A {

}
```

What's the fastest/most efficient way to do this?

Comment: You want to copy just the `A` parts of the `B` objects? You understand they won't be `B` objects any more, right?

Comment: I would do `std::set<B> b( a.begin(), a.end() );`, but haven't checked if there is such constructor. Note that the result may be fewer items. B items that compare unequal may have equal A parts. Regarding "fastest" or "most efficient" that depends on what you know about the sets, and the intended usage, so on. Don't do **premature optimization**, it's plain Evil(TM).

Comment: How do you convert a dog to an animal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is no constant-time approach for this*. The best you can get is by using [`std::copy`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/copy) or [the constructor of `std::set` taking two iterators (aka "range constructor")](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/set/set).

```
std::set<B> bs = ...;

std::set<A> as(bs.begin(), bs.end());
```

---

<sub>*There's a fast but unsafe way to convert it in constant time in the case of `sizeof(B) == sizeof(A)`(that is, `class B` doesn't introduce new members) and if the classes don't use virtual tables (have virtual functions): You could use an unsafe cast. But only do this if you know what you're doing **very well** (it's still undefined behaviour but your compiler might do it as expected). The same holds for the case when you use pointers and when the pointers don't need to be offset (which might be the case when using multiple inheritance or some other cases depending on your compiler).</sub>